# Vue 2.0 - Child Communicate to Parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I cannot seem to get the parent to act on a child's emit. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <!-- Tablet Parent -->
    <li :closeMySibling="closeMyChild">
        <div class="inner-category">
            <ul>
                <!-- Tablet Children / Desktop Parents  -->
                <li v-for="(r, idx) in routes"
                    @mouseover="selected = idx, closeSibling(idx)"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Script:**

```
   closeSibling: function(idx) {
      // message below is showing in console
     console.log("I am emitting " + idx)
     this.$emit('closeMySibling', idx)
    },
    closeChild: function() {
     // message below **IS NOT** showing in console
     console.log('closing my child')
     if (idx !==0){
       (this.$refs['menuItem0'][0]).classList.remove("active")                        
                    }         
    }
```

I am trying to keep this simple; I removed a lot of code.
Basically 4 children belong to a parent. When the parent is moused over, the 1st child's header (index 0) opens with info.

When any of the children are 'moused-over' they emit an event to the parent, first identifying their index and requesting their sibling be closed.

The parent receives the event, and so long as the child requesting the close is not index 0, the parent will close child index 0.

The children are emitting correctly but the parent is not picking up on the emit.

Can someone point out my error.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Changed parent to this => :closeMySibling="closeMyChild()"

Changed child to this => @mouseover="selected = idx; closeSibling(idx)"

Parent receiving call however ....

```
I am emitting 3
closing my child undefined
I am emitting 2
closing my child undefined
I am emitting 1
closing my child undefined
I am emitting 0
closing my child undefined
```

the parent is not getting the idx value

Comment: i think you should `;` instead of `,` in `@mouseover="selected = idx; closeSibling(idx)"`

Comment: peg to emit with @ and not with:

Comment: Hamilton, the parent doesn't respond with '@' only ':'

Comment: @FrancisMazanet the provided code is inside the parent component or in one of the child ones?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I needed to define an idx data property.

Here are the key points:

```
  data() {
    return {
      idx: undefined
   },
   methods: {
     closeSibling: function(idx) {
        console.log("I am emitting" + idx)
        this.$emit('closeMySibling', this.idx = idx)
    },
    closeMyChild: function() {
        console.log('closing my child' + this.idx)
     }
```